# ClassCastException android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams to android.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams is this exception specific to API level?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, layoutparams

I'm trying to add `LinearLayout` dynamically(inflating) to a `GridLayout` as mentioned in the picture below. `GridLayout` is static inside a `ListView` "row" layout.

When i try to add `LinearLayout` to the `GridLayout` I get an error :

```
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout$LayoutParams
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.GridLayout.getLayoutParams1(GridLayout.java:729)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.GridLayout.validateLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:663)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.GridLayout.getLayoutParams(GridLayout.java:734)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.GridLayout.measureChildrenWithMargins(GridLayout.java:866)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.GridLayout.onMeasure(GridLayout.java:894)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1181)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1451)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12922)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1255)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2649)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 12:55:54.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4156):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

As mentioned in the stack trace, AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot cast to GridLayout$LayoutParams. I don't know why this happens?

**NOTE :** The most **weird** part is its happening only in **4.0.4 API 15** devices. It works good in 4.3 and 4.4

[image: version_4.0.4_api_15]

**Update : (Sample Code)**

```
viewHolder.gridLayout1 = (GridLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.sampleGridLayout);
setLinear(viewHolder);

private void setLinear(ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    viewHolder.gridLayout1.removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        LinearLayout matchLayout = (LinearLayout) viewHolder.inflater.inflate(R.id.sampleLinear, parent, false);
        //view populations in matchLayout

        viewHolder.gridLayout1.addView(matchLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: posted sample code @Prag'sシ

Comment: What type of View is the `parent` that you pass to `viewHolder.inflater.inflate()`?

Comment: are you using layoutParams?

Comment: @Tanis.7x its a `ViewGroup` from `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Comment: @Prag'sシ No, i'm not using layout params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `parent` ViewGroup that you are passing in to `viewHolder.inflater.inflate();` is a ListView, not a GridLayout.

Since your adapter is being used to populate a ListView, the `parent` passed into `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` will be a ListView.

When the LayoutInflater inflates your `R.id.sampleLinear` layout, it will give the inflated layout `AbsListView.LayoutParams`, because you are telling the inflater that you intend to put the layout in an AbsListView of some kind.

This will cause the error that you are receiving when you try to put that layout in a GridLayout instead, which requires all children to use `GridLayout.LayoutParams`.

On a side note, you should be passing a layout (in the form of `R.layout.my_layout`) instead of an ID (e.g. `R.id.my_layout`) to your inflater. I'm going to assume this is a typo because otherwise you would be getting a completely different exception.

Comment: yeah I got your point! as mentioned in android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean), passing parent as second parameter and mentioning false in third parameter provides the parent layout params to its child which throws this error. But can justify why this happens in only API 15 devices? Because I already solved this by using `matchLayout.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());` I wanted to know is this API specific?

Comment: Perhaps there was a bug in API 15 that allowed it to work. Unfortunately I really don't know why it would work in 15 (it shouldn't).

Comment: Thanks and the better approach would be to pass null in inflate()? like `inflater.inflate(R.layout.sampleLinear, null);`

Comment: That, or you could pass your GridLayout in as the `parent` instead

Comment: That't not possible in my case as the design would change.